# Calling `expect` from Python without a separate file

Tags: python, ssh, expect

I have the following expect file that I would like to embed in a python script. Currently it is its own separate file that I call from my python script, but I would like to merge the two:

***do_remote.sh***

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -i priv.key user@ip touch test.txt
expect "Enter passphrase for key 'priv.key':"
send "<passphrase>\n"
interact;
```

***call_remote.py***

```py
import os
...
os.system('./do_remote.sh')
...
```

I cannot use any libraries not included with standard python (such as Paramiko or Pexpect).

I do not explicitly need to use the output of the ssh command (but it'd be nice). To be clear, I simply want to only have 1 source code file instead of 2. I am fine with using `os.system()`.

Comment: Which dependency is it you want to get rid of? expect, ssh, or both?  (PS: You don't have any bash files here. `do_remote.sh` is an Expect script written in TCL)

Comment: I don't want to use any third party python libraries

Comment: You are not using any third party python libraries in your code, so... mission accomplished?

Comment: I would like to implement the code in python, not just run the expect file from python

Comment: Then no, this is not really realistic. You would need a Python implementation of SSH which is a rather large undertaking. You can bundle a third party ssh library with your code though, so that nothing needs to be installed on the target machine

Comment: I am fine with running an ssh command via ```os.system()``` or other.

Comment: Are you ok with running an `expect` command via `os.system()` as long as you only end up with a single source file?

Comment: Sure, that would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an Expect script on the command line with `expect -c`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["expect", "-c", """
    spawn ssh -i priv.key user@ip touch test.txt
    expect "Enter passphrase for key 'priv.key':"
    send "<passphrase>\\n"
    interact;
    """])
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not really a bash file as the first line on this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
```

actually states that the interpreter is expect.
Instead of trying to run the shell file from within python, try to launch expect and provide the expect file as the argument:

```
os.system('/usr/bin/expect do_remote.sh')
```